# OpenCV Error reading YUV buffer

Tags: android, opencv, buffer, resolution, yuv

I'm trying to get high resolution uncompressed images through the camera of an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S3), using OpenCV v2.4. I set width and height using VideoCapture.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width) and same for height, but whenever I go to a mid-high resolution, the following error starts appearing:

```
ERROR reading YUV buffer: width=1600, height=1200, size=2880000, receivedSize=1036800
```

I'm guessing it means that the buffer is not big enough to store all the data, which I understand, but there must be some way to allocate a bigger buffer. Does anybody know how, or any workaround?

Thank you!