# How to increase resolution of the openCV camera in android?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, camera, resolution

I am using openCV on android.Now i want to take some more clear images through the camera.

I tried with the following code to change the resolution of the camera ,but all i am getting is the default **640*480** images.

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPictureSize(width,height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Parameter successfully saved but still `mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize()` giving the default same **640*480** resolution.

Please look into the matter !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your camera support a larger resolution? Print the device's camera parameters and check the available resolutions.

```
Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Camera.Parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
```

Do not confuse video recording resolution with picture taking resolution (latter is usually much larger).

Check this post for more details: [How to set camera resolution in Android with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12104868/1085483)

Comment: u are correct ,it is the proper way to change resolution .And my problem , i tried to set a non supportive resolution.